# On evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left [ (\cos x-1)^2 +(\sin x-x)^2 \right ] }{1+x^2}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, roots, contour-integration

The integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left [ (\cos x-1)^2 +(\sin x-x)^2 \right ] }{1+x^2}\text{d}x=-\pi$, can be proven by considering $f(z)= \frac{\ln\left [ e^{i z}-1-iz \right ] }{1+z^2}$.
Because $f(z)$ has no singularity on $H:=\{z\mid z\in\mathbb{C},\Im(z)>0\}$. So our integral equals $2\cdot\frac{1}{2} \cdot2i\pi\cdot\frac{\ln(e^{-1})}{2i} 
=-\pi$ by separating the function into real and imaginary parts(Obviously, the integral of imaginary part is $0$).

While I was trying to generalize it, I conjured up the taylor expansion of $e^{i x}$. And it seemed that
$\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\ln\left [
\left ( \cos x-\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right )^2
+\left(\sin x-\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \right )^2 \right ]}{1+x^2}
\text{d}x
=\pi\ln\left ( \frac{1}{e}-\sum_{n=0}^{2m-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}  \right )$
for any positive integer $m$. The process had no essential difference. For example,
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left [ \left(\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2
+\left(\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{6}\right)^2 \right ] }{1+x^2}\text{d}x=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac13\right).$


The only remaining problem is to show that the integrands are meromorphic functions on $H$,
i.e. the function $f(z)=e^{i z}-\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{i^nz^n}{n!}$ has no zero on $H$ as $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

I will be thankful for your assistance.